# Apache Ambari manual service start

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2, ambari

I have HDFS-HA(namenode high availability) setup in my hadoop cluster(using Apache Ambari).
Now, I have one scenario in which my ambari-server machine(which also consist one Namenode i.e. active/Primary) went offline so that my other Namenode(Standby) was active and running but after some time it went offline too for some reason.Services were offline I mean.I was unable to do any operation.What if I have to start the services manually that is used to start using ambari.
I mean using command-line or something

Answer (score 1):

Services **can** be started from the command line but they should **not** be in an Ambari environment typically. This is because Ambari does more then just start the service when you issue the start/restart command for any given service. Ambari also makes sure the most up to date configuration is written to each node along with other various house keeping type tasks.

You can look at the logs in Ambari when you start/restart a service to see exactly what Ambari does with respect to writing the configuration, other house keeping, and the exact command to start/restart the given service.